# Perform multiple SQL queries with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, joomla

I have a web form that should store data into two different tables in the database. In my includes, I have a php file that performs the necessary queries. The web form should store two pieces of information: The xp value being submitted from the form into the users table, and the article id into the completed_quests table. Individually, the queries work exactly as they should. However, if I try to perform both queries together, only the first query is performed and the second one is ignored. How do I make it so that both queries run once the user hits the submit button?

(edit) I have updated the code. To clarify, there is other code in my php file that defines the variables used in these queries. These are simply the two queries I was trying to run and I needed to know how to run both queries as it seemed to be ignoring the second one (the update).  It is now working, however I am running into an issue of the INSERT query creating duplicate entries.

(edit) I have updated the code again. I used an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to avoid duplicate entries in the table. I made sure that the user id was the primary key in the table and it is now functioning perfectly.

```
mysql_select_db("questroot_joomla", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO arp2i_completed_quests (user_id, content_id) Values ($userId, $currentArticle)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content_id=$currentArticle");

mysql_query( "UPDATE arp2i_users"
. " SET userxp= $userXp"
. " WHERE id = $userId");

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Is that really all your code? I'm surprised it updates anything on any database..... all you're doing is assigning a string to a variable, then creating another string and assigning it nowhere so it's discarded

Comment: MySQL. SQL Server. Pick one.

Comment: Please read the Joomla documentation on how to write database queries for Joomla. You should also **not** using using `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `arp2i_completed_quests` (`user_id`, `content_id`) Values ('$_POST[current_user]', '$_POST[current_article]')";

/* it's not in $sql ->> */   "UPDATE `arp2i_users`
    SET `userxp`= '$_POST[xpValue]'
    WHERE `id` = '$_POST[current_user]'";
```

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `arp2i_completed_quests` (`user_id`, `content_id`) Values
   ('$_POST[current_user]', '$_POST[current_article]');
   UPDATE `arp2i_users`
   SET `userxp`= '$_POST[xpValue]'
   WHERE `id` = '$_POST[current_user]'";
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people here are just answering as though you are using PHP and not a framework that already is designed to handle all this stuff for you and do it safely, including checking for injection etc.  You use a framework to make it simpler and avoid doing unsafe things.  The combination of JForm, JDatabaseQuery and  other parts of the API will handle updating multiple tables just fine, you can see that all over the core.  How you would do it depends on what you are doing, such as is it more like updating the profile table when you are saving user data or is it more like updating the assets table or creating a new tag  when saving content.   What you should do though is stop fighting the API and start using it to your advantage.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add many mysqli_* queries as you want :

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `arp2i_completed_quests` (`user_id`, `content_id`) Values ('".$_POST['current_user']."', '".$_POST['current_article']."')";

mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `arp2i_users` SET `userxp`= '".$_POST['xpValue']."' WHERE `id` = '".$_POST['current_user']."'");
```

Comment: This is Joomla, not raw PHP

Comment: We cannot guess with so little informations.
And even, functions has just to be converted to Joomla database system.